# Maintain size of div on various platforms (e.g. smart phones, tablets)

Tags: javascript, css, html, cross-browser, cross-platform

I made a cross-platform/browser compatible app, but there is one problem.  The browser on a phone or a tablet will resize the page to fit the screen, which is fine, but it also resizes these divs that I use as buttons. In order for them to be pressable by a human finger they should maintain a size of about 50 by 50 pixels, when the page is shrunk they become smaller (not actually smaller, just zoomed out). Is there a way to use javascript to make sure they stay the right size?
--Ashley

Comment: Some code to see would make it immense easier to help

Comment: You can change your username in your profile. That way you don't have to sign your questions. http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/1118684

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many mobile devices pretend to be larger than they are to show everything on the page, you can correct this—at least on some mobile devices—by adding this in the `head` of your document:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you just specify your exact width and height of the button in your css class.
Like `width:50px; height:50px`

Comment: Yes, thats what I do, but they shrink the view, like scale it by .5, so the result is a smaller square.